# Keycloack in prod is stuck on loading admin page

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, keycloak

I have a keycloak server deployed with docker behind a nginx reverse proxy.
In dev mode all is working fine, but since I am trying to deploy it in prod I can acces the app but when I want to config my server from the admin console I'm stuck in this page :

[image]

## Docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
   postgresql:
     image: postgres:latest
     command: postgres -c 'max_connections=200'
     networks:
       - keycloak-net
       - postgresql-net
     restart: always
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_USER=keycloak
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
       - POSTGRES_DB=keycloak
     volumes:
       - ./keycloak/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data


   keycloak:
     image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.3
     networks:
       - proxy-net
       - keycloak-net
     restart: always
     command: start --spi-truststore-file-file /etc/x509/https/truststore.jks --spi-truststore-file-password password --spi-truststore-file-hostname-verification-policy ANY
     environment:
       - KC_HOSTNAME=keycloak
       - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
       - KC_PROXY=edge
       - KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
       - KC_DB=postgres
       - KC_DB_URL_HOST=postgresql
       - KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=keycloak
       - KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
       - KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
       - KC_DB_SCHEMA=public
       - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
       - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
     depends_on:
       - postgresql
     volumes:
       - ./keycloak/stores:/etc/x509/https

networks:
    proxy-net:
        external: true
    keycloak-net:
        driver: bridge
    postgresql-net:
        driver: bridge
```

## Keycloak logs on startup

```
keycloak_1     | Next time you run the server, just run:
keycloak_1     | 
keycloak_1     |        kc.sh start --optimized --spi-truststore-file-file=/etc/x509/https/truststore.jks --spi-truststore-file-password=password --spi-truststore-file-hostname-verification-policy=ANY
keycloak_1     | 
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:15:53,562 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider] (main) Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: keycloak, Strict HTTPS: false, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: true
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:15:57,778 WARN  [io.quarkus.agroal.runtime.DataSources] (main) Datasource <default> enables XA but transaction recovery is not enabled. Please enable transaction recovery by setting quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true, otherwise data may be lost if the application is terminated abruptly
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:00,549 INFO  [org.keycloak.broker.provider.AbstractIdentityProviderMapper] (main) Registering class org.keycloak.broker.provider.mappersync.ConfigSyncEventListener
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:00,555 WARN  [org.infinispan.PERSISTENCE] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000554: jboss-marshalling is deprecated and planned for removal
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:00,658 WARN  [org.infinispan.CONFIG] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000569: Unable to persist Infinispan internal caches as no global state enabled
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:00,742 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.core.JBossUserMarshaller'
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:01,352 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Triskaidekaphobia' 13.0.10.Final
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:01,673 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel `ISPN`
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:01,675 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000088: Unable to use any JGroups configuration mechanisms provided in properties {}. Using default JGroups configuration!
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:01,866 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 1.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:01,869 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 20.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:01,870 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the send buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 1.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:01,872 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.UDP] (keycloak-cache-init) JGRP000015: the receive buffer of socket MulticastSocket was set to 25.00MB, but the OS only allocated 212.99KB
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:03,900 INFO  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) 4b41e052f453-15754: no members discovered after 2003 ms: creating cluster as coordinator
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:03,933 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ISPN: [4b41e052f453-15754|0] (1) [4b41e052f453-15754]
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:03,947 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000079: Channel `ISPN` local address is `4b41e052f453-15754`, physical addresses are `[192.168.16.3:54114]`
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:05,038 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (main) Node name: 4b41e052f453-15754, Site name: null
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:06,893 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Keycloak 20.0.3 on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.13.6.Final) started in 17.483s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:06,897 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile prod activated. 
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:06,899 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, jdbc-h2, jdbc-mariadb, jdbc-mssql, jdbc-mysql, jdbc-oracle, jdbc-postgresql, keycloak, logging-gelf, narayana-jta, reactive-routes, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-metrics, vault, vertx]
keycloak_1     | 2023-01-19 18:16:07,033 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (main) KC-SERVICES0010: Failed to add user 'admin' to realm 'master': user with username exists
```

Note that the error at the end append beacause my db has already an admin.
I have the same issue when strating from an empty db.

## nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name myserver.fr;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/myserver.fr/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/myserver.fr/privkey.pem;
        
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080;
    }
}
```

## Network console web browser

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help !

I have tried a lot of configuration, I saw a lot of time that adding KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false on env variable is the solution. I tried but it does not work..

Comment: What do the browser developer tools tell you?  I too have seen issues with the hostname configuration but the browser tools may give you a hint.

Comment: I have updated my post but I don't found something really clear.. Maybe you are talking about another tool ?

Comment: Thank you @stdunbar , with your comment I was able to solve the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @stdunbar I was able to solve this.

I had set KC_HOSTNAME to keycloak which is the hostname of the container in my docker network.

To solve my problem I set the KC_HOSTNAME to the real hostname accessible from browser : keycloak.mydomain.fr

Comment: Can you provide another example of a hostname? I am still stuck

Comment: I can help you, my domain is keycloak.moonlysoft.com, so I will add 
KC_HOSTNAME: 'keycloak.moonlysoft.com'

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck too. I have set KC_HOSTNAME: {"timestamp":"2023-12-29T00:24:46.748Z","sequence":40,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.hostname.DefaultHostnameProvider","level":"INFO","message":"Hostname settings: Base URL: <unset>, Hostname: localtest.myname.com, Strict HTTPS: true, Path: <request>, Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: <unset>, Admin: <request>, Port: -1, Proxied: true","threadName":"main","threadId":1,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-5fcbf5b8dc-vprzw","processName":"QuarkusEntryPoint","processId":1}

Comment: Nevermind. I found my solution. I was setting KC_PROXY as per the docs but I'm not behind one. Tried to set it to "none" at first, and that didn't work. Removing the environment variable completely got me working properly.